# How to get the right indentation and new line when adding a new line between brackets?

Tags: indentation

So I am curious about one thing:
when I am between two brackets (`{`) in vim (or nvim), and I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> I go from this (where the pipe sign is the cursor):

```
getUsers(){|}
```

to this:

```
getUsers(){
|}
```

How can I customize the editor to get this instead:

```
getUsers(){
··|
}
```

Comment: Well, I am not asking about just indentation. So what I am asking is, when I oppen a new bracket, vim auto closes it and puts the cursor between those brackets.
When I hit enter though, I want to basically add two <CR> and put the cursor in the middle line and idented, (as I tried to mention in the question)

Comment: So from lacking from a more, lets say, elegant way, this is my solution:
`inoremap <C-CR> <CR><CR><Up><Tab>`
(And on another note, I do not know how to remove the duplicate tag, when clearly my question isn't a duplicate as statox suggested...)